# Reactjs - How to see method definition in props with VSCode

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35855781/having-services-in-react-application), one way in reactjs to reuse code is to put it in a "container" component, then pass it down to its child via props. Cool.

Problems rise to me when, in my IDE (VSCode), I need to go to the method/property implementation: if code is imported via oldSchool "import", then everything works by "ctrl+clicking" the method name; but if I'm inspecting a method/property passed via props by the parent component, then "ctrl+click" on the method name is useless:

```
<div onClick={props.**methodFromParent**()}>Click me</div>
```

That's pretty obvuios, because there are no refs in my child code about the parent component itself (they get composited in another component ad-hoc). So is there a way to have this feature back? Because is very usefull to me.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Passing a function as a prop and executing it in a child component is perfectly fine.

Comment: Sounds like you need proptypes (https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) or typescript (https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: @Tobi I know that. My prolem is in my IDE: ctrl+click the method inside the child doesn't redirect me to the method implementation

Comment: Ah, okay sorry. Yeah then the approach of @AndréKrosby is the right one, as there are no type and therefore definition references.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be possible.
If you define a method in the parent and pass it to the child you are not passing the mothod. What you actually are passing is a reference to a function and the child executes that function.
Like you mentioned it is possible to reuse code that way. The child doesn't know what method will be passed. It is not a static binding. So the IDE can't know either.

You could have something like:

```
// Parent component
const add = (a,b) => return a+b;
const sub = (a,b) => return a-b;
 
return ( <>
  <child num=4 action={add}>
  <child num=7 action={sub}>
</>);
```

```
// Child component
return (
  <div>The result is {props.action(10, props.num)}</div>
);
```

As you see the property "action" doesn't relate to any particular method on the parent, it is just a property and the IDE can't show you a definition.